# problem to get toplinks and minicart

Tags: magento-1.9, mini-cart, toplinks

when I am calling

`echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks')` and `echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_minicart')`

in **`header.phtml`** file than it outputs like

`<!-- fpc 3d9a9fce22ac37444d94bbb2adc6cbdf01debde2 -->`

Is anybody having the same issue. if yes than please tell me how to solve it because i search related to this but i did't found anything about it.

Any help will appreciated.

This is header.phtml

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="topbar">
        <div class="topLinks pull-left">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <div class="quickaccess-toggle hidden-lg hidden-md">
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>                                                        
            </div>
            <div class="inner-toggle">
                <div class="language pull-left">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <div class="form-language dropdown" style="display: none;">               
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Country">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Country') ?><span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>                                            
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('country')->toHtml(); ?>
             </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_currency') ?>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-right inner pull-right">
            <div class="pull-right">  
                <div class="inner-toggle">
                    <div class="cart-top">
                        <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_minicart'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="quick-access pull-right">
                <div class="quickaccess-toggle hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>                                                        
                </div>
                <div class="inner-toggle">
                    <div class="top-search pull-right">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                    </div>      
                </div>      
            </div>      
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your header file code.

Comment: @SHPatel I just add code.. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

i just got answer.

It's a problem with `Full Page Cache` in `Cache Manegement`

i just disable it and it works fine.